# Engine turns but won't start -- 3 months later

Tags: cranks-wont-run, lincoln, towncar

I'm not a car guru. I'm trying to start a 2004 Lincoln Town Car. This is the first time I've tried to start the car since coming back to town after 3 months out of town. The engine turns over, but won't start.

The battery is not the issue. I bought a new battery right before going out of town and had it disconnected from the car during the past 3 months. When I put the key in the ignition, the radio, AC, etc all come on without issue.

Half of the gas is old. I rarely drove the car before going out of town, so the tank was filled 6 months ago. It had 6 old gallons in it when I came home. I got some fresh gasoline from the gas station and added it to the tank. So now the tank has 6 gallons of 6-month-old gas, and 5 gallons of fresh gas.

I don't know what the issue is here, or how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the car attempt to start at all? Sputter, cough, chug, what have you? Or does it just turn over and over and over and won't do anything but spin around?

Comment: It makes a sound like "buh-buh-buh-buh-buh" as long as I turn the key. The normal sound an engine makes during the first second of starting up. I tried swapping out the fuel pump relay for a fresh one. That didn't help.

Comment: There's a fuel pump cut off switch in the trunk ... have you checked it to see if it was tripped for some reason?

Comment: The switch in the trunk was not tripped. I pressed it anyways. Nothing changed after pressing it.

Comment: I take it the engine in question is the 4.6L V8?

Comment: Yes. It has the standard engine for Town Car. The belt on the engine rotates when turning the key.

Comment: Have you checked fuel pressure at the rail?

Comment: I haven't heard of that before. Will I need to buy some pieces of equipment to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, unless you know someone who has one. The fuel rail is what feeds fuel to the injectors. If you don't have the correct fuel pressure, the engine isn't going to want to start (or could also run, but run terribly).

Comment: If I test the fuel pressure, what is a good score and what is a bad score? Does a bad score mean I have to replace the fuel pump?

Comment: I believe Fords run at 35-40psi with key on and engine off. Also check it with the engine cranking. Low fuel pressure could either be the pump or the relay. Check the relay first. It should be in the underhood fuse panel.